# Wordpress Default Widgets

Tags: wordpress, themes

Ive created a wordpress theme and when I submitted it to their directory I was told I needed to have some default widgets. Ive been trying to find out how to do this but can't find anything on the matter.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Just use *the_widget()* function:

```
if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar() && !is_active_sidebar( 'your-example-widget-area' ) ) {
echo '<div>';
    the_widget(
        'WP_Widget_Text'
        ,array(
            'title'     => 'example title'
            ,'text'     => '
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                    Aenean et quam a ante sodales feugiat. Aliquam et vulputate turpis. 
                    Mauris quis sodales neque. Sed vestibulum faucibus eros nec tincidunt. 
                    Integer tortor magna, suscipit vitae ultricies vel, vehicula sit amet sapien. 
                </p>
            '
            ,'filter'   => ''
        )
        ,array(
            'before_widget' => '<div class="widget-container">'
            ,'after_widget' => '</div>'
            ,'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">'
            ,'after_title'  => '</h3>'
        )
    );
echo '</div>'; } elseif( is_active_sidebar( 'your-example-widget-area' ) ) {
echo '<div>';
    dynamic_sidebar( 'your-example-widget-area' );  
echo '</div>';     } // endif;
```

Hope that helps. (Sry, for the strange }elseif position. Formatting get's wrong at the moment.)

Comment: Btw: This code makes shure that the wp function dynamic_sidebar exists, so it's backward compatible too.

Answer (score -3):

Not too hard to search at Wordpress :)

[Widgeizing themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes)

[Widgets API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugins/WordPress_Widgets_Api)

[How to create widgets](http://www.lonewolfdesigns.co.uk/create-wordpress-widgets/)